# Cannot iterate through json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am building a json object with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/_layouts/WP/Handler.aspx/GetProductAssets",
        data: '{ "productId": "'+productcode+'" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var order = "";
            var data = response.d;
            var Groups = [];
            var json = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                if($.inArray(value.AssetType, Groups) == -1){
                    Groups.push(value.AssetType);
                    }

            });
            $.each(Groups, function(key, value){
                var groupassets = [];
                $.each(data, function(key2, value2){

                if(value2.AssetType == value)
                        groupassets.push(value2);
                });

                json.push("{'group': '" + value + "', 'assets': " + groupassets + "}");
            });
            alert(json);
            $.get('/common/js/assettemplate.htm', function (template) {
                 $('body').append(template);
                $("#assetTemplate").tmpl(json).appendTo("#support-download-results");
            });
        },

    });
```

The json object that is created and alerted in the code, produces the following:

```
{'group': 'test', 'assets': [object Object]}, {'group': 'test2', 'assets': [object Object]}
```

When I try to access by using `json[0].group` i get `undefined`.  Am I not accessing or building this json object correctly?  I cant seem to get any of the values of the data, they all come up as undefined.

Comment: I think you don't want to create JSON at all.... I think you should create a JavaScript object.

Comment: You seem to be looping through a JSON object to create another JSON object -- may I ask why?

Comment: If your json variable were an array containing two objects, when you alert() it, you would see "[object Object],[object Object]" and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so... what you have there are two JSON objs. You need to wrap them in an brackets so that they are in an array. Then you can say json[0].group:

```
[{'group': 'test', 'assets': {}}, {'group': 'test2', 'assets': {}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupassets` is an object not a string. You'll have to stringify it before calling `json.push`

Answer (score 0):

You should take the response.d returned from your web service and bind that to the template. You seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary conversions in between.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of strings. You cannot access `json[0].group`, because `jons[0]` is a string and strings don't have a `group` attribute.

Just add objects to the array:

```
json.push({group: value, assets: groupassets})
```

As I already said in my comment, you probably don't want JSON and what you create is actually not JSON.